libvirt for local usage - how do I preserve access rights on my local images?
My context is:

I am a developer, working on a project which needs to be run on a separate system (a VM will work very well),
I want to use libvirt to be able to create these separate VMs, and still have access to the virt-manager GUI to explore/debug the VMs setup,
my scope is to create throwaway VMs on my local workstation, with me as the sole user who interacts with libvirt,
I want to script the provisioning and startup of some throwaway VMs from the code of my local workstation (part of that code generates disk images, like .iso or .qcow2 files)

My issue is:
when I create a VM through a script, and use a local image (for example: a .iso or a .qcow2 file), libvirt messes with the file's rights: by default, it switches the owner:group to libvirt-qemu:kvm, and the access rights to -rw-r--r--.
I know of a way to prevent that:
if I declare a storage pool on the directory -- and take care to set the owner:group of said pool to my own uid:gid -- and also declare a volume for target file -- again: and declare that said volume should have my uid:gid -- then I can still access the volume files (as in: ls, or rm obsolete volumes ...).
It is however cumbersome to have to define a volume each time.

I certainly understand that libvirt aims at presenting features to manage VM accesses in a production context, it so happens that in my use case (developer / testing throwaway VMs) this gets in the way.
My question:
is there a way to tell libvirt "leave the access rights on these images as they are" ?
either globally/per directory/at VM creation ?

libvirt is very clumsy for a personal use. That said, have you tried to accomplish this with POSIX ACLs?
